# What's happening in this Base64?

Tags: base64

I'm trying to send a client to a URL on their accounting system for a specific account. The URL format is:

```
https://accountingsystem.com/Edit/CustomerEdit.aspx?CustomerId=MwA0ADEANQA4ADYAMgA=-MzQxNTg2Mg==
```

The Customer ID is 3415862, which when encoded as Base64, does indeed give me MzQxNTg2Mg==. However, I don't know where MwA0ADEANQA4ADYAMgA=- comes from, or how to calculate it. What's also confusing is this:

```
$ echo MwA0ADEANQA4ADYAMgA=-MzQxNTg2Mg== | base64 -D -d
<Info>: Read 34 bytes.
<Info>: Decoded to 14 bytes.
<Info>: Wrote 14 bytes.
3415862%

$ echo MwA0ADEANQA4ADYAMgA= | base64 -D -d
<Info>: Read 21 bytes.
<Info>: Decoded to 14 bytes.
<Info>: Wrote 14 bytes.
3415862%

$ echo MzQxNTg2Mg== | base64 -D -d
<Info>: Read 13 bytes.
<Info>: Decoded to 7 bytes.
<Info>: Wrote 7 bytes.
3415862%
```

Can someone elucidate this conundrum?

In anticipation,
J

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference:

`MwA0ADEANQA4ADYAMgA=` decodes to hexadecimal `3300340031003500380036003200`

and

`MzQxNTg2Mg==` decodes to hexadecimal `33343135383632`

While both result to the string `3415862`, the difference is that the first one is encoded from a UTF-16 string and the second one is encoded from UTF-8 or ASCII.

This said, I have no idea why they would combine both formats in one value. Maybe they just use the '-' sign to indicate that both formats are allowed.

Comment: Thanks Wouter! Now I have to figure out how to encode that in Javascript, but I'll ask that in a separate question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript